# How to add attributes to soap header?

Tags: java, soap, axis, soap-client

I want to add attributes to soap header like

```
    <soapenv:Header attr="somevalue"attr1="somevalue"/>
```

Using Axis 1. But the API won't let me do this. I am getting this element inside one more header element like

```
    <soapenv:Header>
        <soapenv:Header attr="somevalue"attr1="somevalue"/>
    </soapenv:Header>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Here is the code to add header

```
SOAPFactory factory = SOAPFactory.newInstance();
String prefix = "soapenv";
String uri="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
SOAPElement Elem;
Elem = factory.createElement("Header",prefix,uri);
Elem.addAttribute(QName.valueOf("attr"), "value");
Elem.addAttribute(QName.valueOf("attr"), "value");
SOAPHeaderElement soapheader=new SOAPHeaderElement(Elem);
stub.setHeader(soapheader);
```